# Is there a one line way of saying this?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Pretty simple probably for someone. Is there a way to say this in one line of code?

```
if word.startswith('^') or word.startswith('@'):
    truth = True
else: 
    truth = False
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this will be the shortest one:

```
truth = word.startswith(('^','@'))
```

From docs (look at the last line):

```
startswith(...)
    S.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]]) -> bool

    Return True if S starts with the specified prefix, False otherwise.
    With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
    With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
    prefix can also be a tuple of strings to try.
```

Comment: you win! hey its you again! hi man! already gave the answer to the first dude tho... thanks!

Comment: @colonq: You can (and should) un-accept the other answer and accept this one.

Comment: go on then, seeing as its you ;)

Answer (score 8):

The boolean expression (`word.startswith('^') or word.startswith('@')`) returns a boolean value, which can then be assigned to a variable, so:

```
truth = (word.startswith('^') or word.startswith('@'))
```

is perfectly valid.

Comment: oh, thats embarrassing, thought i already tried that and it didnt work! thankyou sir.

Comment: big up york uni! used to know a bloke there that did 3d sound experiments.

Comment: This is Oh so turgid. Get rid of the surperfluous parentheses for a start. Then read the docs and/or the answer by @ovgolovin

Comment: @JohnMachin As a disclaimer, I am not a Python programmer. The main point I wanted to put across is the fact that a boolean expression actually has a value, which many programmers do not realise as they start out. I would RTFM, but since the question covers a syntax issue which most languages support, there was no point Googling for another ten minutes.

Comment: @slugonamission: That's astonishing. How could any type of expression not have a value? You must be talking about coders, not programmers.

Comment: @JohnMachin: well, yeah. It's just one of those basic things you never realise properly when picking up a language, or you think a conditional construct performs some sort of black magic.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
truth = word.startswith('^') or word.startswith('@')
```

Answer (score 1):

`truth = word and word[0] in '^@'`

This will do the job very rapidly (no method call involved) but is limited to one-byte prefixes and will set `truth` to the value of `word` if `word` is `''`, `None`, `0`, etc. And it would/should be tossed out in a code review of more than minimal rigor.

Comment: that's an interesting approach